# Proof verification of: Show $f$ has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Question:

If $f:[0,1]→[0,1]$ is increasing function. Suppose $0<f(0),f(1)<1$. Show $f$ has fixed point.

My attempt:

Let $S=\{x:f(x)-x\geq 0\}$. $S$ is bounded above by $1$ hence $SupS$ exists. Let $r=SupS$. I will show that $f(r)=r$.

Since $f$ is an increasing function, then by the monotone function theorem, we have that $f(r-),f(r+)$ exist and:
$$f(r-)\leq f(r) \leq f(r+)$$

$\forall \epsilon >0$,

We have that $f(r+\epsilon)<r+\epsilon$ since otherwise it would contradict that $r$ is the supremum of $S$. We also have by monotonicity that $f(r)<f(r+\epsilon) <r+\epsilon$

We also have that by the Supremum property, $\exists c\in S$ such that $r-\epsilon \leq c \leq r$. Since $c\in S$ and by monotonicity, then $f(r)\geq f(c)\geq c \geq r-\epsilon $

Hence $r-\epsilon < f(r) < r+\epsilon \Rightarrow |f(r)-r|<\epsilon \Rightarrow f(r)=r$.

Any problem with the proof or any suggestions to improve my proof writing?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks good. The only thing that I would suggest is to explicitly say why $S$ must be non-empty(fairly easy) and justify why $r\neq 1$, which you use implicitly in your proof(a little trickier, but still not bad).